# How to achieve automatic height with jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid, height

I was under the impression that `height:auto` option was viable as it's stated in the documentation
http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options

But it turns out that I am getting a JS auto is undefined error.

```
0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'auto' is undefined
```

Is there a way to have an auto height for jqgrid?

ETA:
I had to use

```
height:"auto"
```

As always, the documentation is lacking examples.

Answer (score 0):

its very easy. If you need height of the grid to fit in browser window here is how to do that:

```
var realheight = $(window).innerHeight()-110;    
height:realheight
```